# Who derived $\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx = \Pi(s-1)/n^s$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, reference-request, math-history

Does anyone know the name of the paper in which this equation first appeared? Thank you!
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx = \Pi(s-1)/n^s$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was (almost certainly) Euler. For example, we find it in E675, *De valoribus integralium a termino variabilis $x=0$ usque ad $x=\infty$ extensorum* (1781). A translation of this paper may be found [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4640). At the bottom of p. 3 of the translation one finds

> §8. I first put $x=ky$, and because both terms of the integral stay the same, it will be 
>   $$k^n \int y^{n−1}\partial y \cdot e^{−ky}= \Delta, $$
>   where this formula is also extended from $y= 0$ up to $y=\infty$; then dividing this by $k^n$ we will have
>   $$ \int y^{n−1}\partial y \cdot e^{−ky}=\frac{\Delta}{k^n} $$,where it should however be noted that no negative numbers can be taken for $k$, as otherwise the formula $e^{−ky}$ would no longer vanish in the case $y=\infty$;and these are the only values which ought to be excluded here, so that even imaginary values could be used in place of $k$, and then I pursued these laborious integrations.

(And yes, Euler does consider non-integer $n$ in the paper: he discusses $n=1/2$ later on.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

That formula is easily seen to be equivalent to the integral definition of the Gamma function, introduced by Euler in a letter to Goldbach in 1730. (Note that $\Pi(s-1)=\Gamma(s)$.)

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#18th_century:_Euler_and_Stirling).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it was in Riemann's *[On the number of primes less than a given magnitude](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf)*. It's the second formula that appears there.

Comment: If the question is really about the formula *exactly* as presented, I suppose you win. ;-)

Comment: Yes. So Riemann writes "on making use of the equation" as if the equation is already established, so I am wondering where it came from, or if it is "obvious."

Comment: Hey! It's Riemann that we're talking about. Of course it was obvious to him.

Comment: But the rest of the paper is more pedagogical... the difference in flow doesn't make sense!

Comment: It's “obvious” in the sense that it only requires substituting $x=t/n$ in the integral. To Riemann, and most likely to his intended audience, that is no great stretch.